# Rifle in Vault 15

Tags: fallout

I am reliving old RPG glory in Fallout 1. I am currently in Vault 15 and I remember that you can find the hunting rifle somewhere in the bathroom on the 2nd level. I check all the bathrooms but can't find the rifle. I read that this was introduced past patch version v1.15 but my version is 1.20 from steam, european release, so it should apply.

Can anyone tell me which room is it in? or am I searching the wrong floor?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in the #1 bathroom in your screenshot.

According to [this No mutants allowed site](http://www.nma-fallout.com/content.php?page=fo-maps-v15), the rifle is

> In V.15 in the living section there is also a hunting rifle in the lower right bathroom. once in the bathroom it is in the north west corner.

This is also confirmed by [Good Old Games forum](http://www.gog.com/forum/fallout_series/hunting_rifle_in_vault_15)

> EDIT: Got it. The bathroom in the southwest corner, the rifle is infront on the toilet (i.e. the north west corner of the bathroom. Move the mouse around the area until the rifle lights up. Its a little hard to see - I would have screenshotted it but I was so exicted to have found it I picked it up straight away.

[image]

Comment: Found it! I thought that I already checked there, anyway great answer man.

Comment: Yeah, it's hidden until you point mouse on exact place.